# Is there a way to change type int to type char by prototyping?

Tags: c++

I am making a project.
This is a function declaration in a separate file.

```
void PrintLines(int characterValue, int characterCount, int lineCount)
```

When I prototype in my main file I use:

```
void PrintLines(char characterValue, int characterCount, int lineCount);
```

This will not compile. Are there any methods I can use to make it type char in the main method without changing the first int type(in the other file?

I think I have to type cast. Just have to figure out how.

Basically, the code has to be

```
 void PrintLines(int characterValue, int characterCount, int lineCount)
```

for file 1 and

```
 void PrintLines(char characterValue, int characterCount, int lineCount);
```

for main. I might need to convert ASCII to char...

Comment: Why? You have to motivate your seemingly strange desire.

Comment: Looks like a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I have to look up type casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload functions like this but the two function have a different signature, i.e., during linking it will fail. I'm not sure what you try to achieve but it might work to delegate:

```
void PrintLines(char cv, int cc, int lc) {
    PrintLines(int(cv), cc, lc);
}
```

Comment: honestly my I have restrictions due to help me learn. But it seems to waste time and make me frustrated.

Comment: Consider using the more C++-style `static_cast`.

Comment: @daknøk: I didn't cast but used the constructor notation I would prefer over a `static_cast<T>()` for any user-defined type, as well!

Comment: Constructor *notation*. It’s still a cast since `int` is a primitive type.

Comment: Ok I got it, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a `char` instead of an `int` as the first argument, then simply do so. Example:

```
int x, y;
char c;
// ...
PrintLines(c, x, y);
```

`char` can be implicitly casted to `int` in C++. You can also do a manual cast to `int` instead if you prefer:

```
PrintLines(static_cast<int>(c), x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.

cout << (char) characterValue;

in the file with the function.

I was getting 65 for A so I switched it back to A.